# Type hint deftype in Clojure macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I'm trying to create a macro that makes a Clojure `deftype`and which requires type hints to be generated. I currently have some test code:

```
(defmacro test-macro [n]
  (let [obj-sym (gensym "obj")
    p0 (with-meta 'p0 {:tag java.lang.Object})
    p1 (with-meta 'p1 {:tag java.lang.Integer/TYPE})
    r0 (with-meta 'remove {:tag java.lang.Boolean/TYPE})
    r1 (with-meta 'remove {:tag java.lang.Object})]
`(deftype ~n [~obj-sym]
   java.util.List
   (~r0 [_ ~p0] (.remove ~obj-sym ~p0))
   (~r1 [_ ~p1] (.remove ~obj-sym ~p1)))))
```

When it returns:

```
(test-macro test-it)
;clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must hint overloaded method: remove, ...
```

As a guide, it should produce something equivalent to:

```
(clojure.core/deftype ThisWorks [obj-5546]
  java.util.List
   (#^"boolean" remove [_ ^java.lang.Object p0-object] (.remove obj-5546 p0-object))
   (^{:tag "java.lang.Object"} remove [_ ^int p0-int] (.remove obj-5546 p0-int)))
```

It looks like I am type hinting the wrong thing, or the meta data isn't being passed. Other than a fix for the immediate problem, bonus points if you can help out with the more general "meta" problem: how to debug a macro which manipulates metadata as macroexpand isn't very useful here..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `:tag` metadata is supposed to be a symbol, not a class object (since, after all, a symbol is all you can type as code in a non-macro situation: I can't embed the Class object `int` itself in my code!). So rather than `Integer/TYPE`, you just want `'int`, and similarly for all your other typehints.

Comment: Hmm. If I change the type hints in the macro to 'int, 'boolean and 'java.lang.Object, I get java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't type hint a primitive local.

Comment: If I could get the macro to insert the code to create the type hint, this would be a solution, but I can't insert reader macros and inserting the "with-meta" into the deftype doesn't work either (I tried to write a deftype [i.e. not even generating it with a macro] using with-meta for type hinting instead of reader macros and couldn't get it to work).

Comment: The version with `with-meta` (and using symbols instead of class objects) is identical to what you would produce with reader macros. If you write `(... (remove [_ ^int x] (.remove obj ^int x)))` you get the same behavior. Instead, make sure to *not* include the type-hint on the second occurrence of `x`: it should just be `(.remove obj x)`.